# How to show Buddy-press created groups inside Comet-Chat?

Tags: wordpress, buddypress, cometchat

I have installed buddy-press and comet-chat plugins. But i need to show buddy-press groups and its members inside the comet-chat. But they are not showing up. Only the groups created inside comet-chat are visible in comet-chat area. I need some help or clue how to bring or show buddy press groups to the comet-chat.

I have tried all the documentations from comet-chat as well buddy-press. But no good help from them. I have set all the sync and bind buddy-press to comet-chat options, still not working. used the following short-code on a page to show comet chat.

```
[cometchat layout='embedded' width='990' height='600']
```

Please help me , thanks.

Comment: can you share the link which article you followed ?

Comment: Because some this one is out dated https://support.cometchat.com/documentation/php/installing-cometchat/ready-integrations/buddypress/

Comment: Followed most of them, including latest docs, but no where helping about showing buddy-press groups to comet-chat groups.

Comment: I have never before worked on buddy press so exactly i ddid't get the point.
But i tried if i found something i will get back to you.

Comment: @LaReyna there is a setting in WordPress -> CometChat -> BuddyPress Settings -> "Synchronize BuddyPress Groups with CometChat"